# Get a count of Prisoners who have either a job or are taking a class

Tags: mysql

Tables are as follows:

```
Person
person_ssn
first_name
middle_name
last_name


Prisoner
prisoner_id
person_ssn

Work
prisoner_id
job_id

Class
prisoner_id
class_id
```

I am interested in getting the count of prisoners that have Work or Class. Any tips are appreciated.

What I have so far

```
select count(prisoner.prisoner_id)
FROM prisoner
INNER JOIN work on prisoner.prisoner_id = work.prisoner_id
INNER JOIN school on prisoner.prisoner_id = school.prisoner_id;
```

This seems to be returning the count of prisoners who both have work and are in school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *left* joins, but require that at least one join succeeds by checking that a column in the joined table is not null (missed left joins have all nulls in columns the joined table):

```
select count(distinct prisoner.prisoner_id)
from prisoner
left join work on prisoner.prisoner_id = work.prisoner_id
left join school on prisoner.prisoner_id = school.prisoner_id
where work.prisoner_id is not null
or school.prisoner_id is not null
```

Note that I added `distinct` to the count, in case the prisoner had multiple jobs or was taking multiple classes, which would otherwise count the prisoner multiple times.

Comment: I had to change 'unique' to 'distinct', but this works. Cheers!

Comment: Doh! I meant distinct... coffee hasn't kicked in yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You used the second inner join  on the first inner join result - that means you check for the intersection of prisoner and working prisoner and then you check the intersection of working prisoner and those who take class

Try this:

```
select count(*) from (
   (select * from 
      prisoner inner join work on prisoner.prisoner_id = work.prisoner_id) as first
   union
   (select * from
      prisoner inner join class on prisoner.prisoner_id = class.prisoner_id) as second);
```

Comment: I receieve a Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias with your implementation.

Comment: try adding alias to each inner query

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way to approach this query is to use `exists`:

```
select count(*)
from prisoners p
where exists (select 1 from work w where w.prisoner_id = p.prisoner_id) or
      exists (select 1 from class c where c.prisoner_id = p.prisoner_id);
```

This works best with indexes on `work(prisoner_id)` and `class(prisoner_id)`.